# Can IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition support Ultimate's features somehow?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I know that Community ediition doesn't support certain features of Ultimate but I want to know that there is NO way to make these features to run in anyway. For example, the Enterprise development (e.g. Tomcat, Glassfish, Oracle, etc.) or Web development (e.g. Spring, HTML5, etc. ). So, if I have to run these kind of development somehow can I succeed in doing these things only with the Community edition or I am locked and not able to do such things. Say, I don't have the luxury to go to Ultimate for some reason.

Comment: It's open-source, so there's nothing to stop you writing these features yourself.

Comment: So you are looking for advice on how to hack (as in the illegal activety) IDEA? Use what is freely available or pay for it.

Comment: As it stands it is basically asking for advice on performing an illegal activity.

Comment: I simply asks as if I had eclipse that supports all these features if I was able to do the same thing with Community edition. Only that.

Comment: Or programming with eclipse is illegal?

Comment: @StathisAndronikos eclipse supports a lot of the features available with intellij ultimate - in particualr hot deploy with tomcat/glassfish et all. But intellij is worth the money imho, as eclipse is ugly and buggy.

Comment: Ultimate is the best available choice. Community is not just enough.

Comment: This question could be improved by citing more specific examples, one such example would be JavaScript extensions / helpers offering functionality normally exclusive to UE but not in violation of the EULA.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are a cheapskate use the EAP from [Jetbrain's Confluence page](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+13+EAP).

The early access might have bugs - but it's free, has all the features of the Ultimate edition, and then some.

Comment: So, you say that there is no way to overcome the support problem with Community Edition, am I right?

Comment: @StathisAndronikos yes obviously. you are asking how to get paid for sopftware for free. if there was a way to do what you ask why would anyone pay for the ultimate version.

Comment: my real objective is to decide if I have to go with eclipse or not. If there is a way to go with Community Edition and 'somehow' don't face any problem then ok otherwise it's better to go with eclipse or maybe with what you suggest.

Comment: i used eclipse for ten years and switched to intellij about 2yrs ago. i wish i had it sooner. i use ultimate. try the eap out its fully featured like utlimate. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/168332/2297

Comment: @StathisAndronikos Also remember IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate has a 30 day free trial. So you can try it for 30 days before making your decision. 10 years ago it only took me 2 days of that 30 day trial  to decide to buy it and I haven't looked back since. Worth every penny. And when you break it down, a personal license costs 80 cents (US) a work day (50 week year, 5 days a week) for the first year, and 40 cents a day after if you upgrade every year. So the question becomes, after trying it, do you like IntelliJ IDEA enough to spend 80 cents a day.

Comment: My question has been answered. Community edition is not supporting certain things & Ultimate is the best available choice.

Comment: This does not answer the question. EAP versions are not the community edition, and they are not free either (they require a license, just like the release versions).

Comment: @sleske you don't need a paid license, hence the ten upvotes and accepted answer

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Yes, you do. The EAP versions are licensed just like the release versions - the license in the download bundle is the same. This is confirmed on the [page for IDEA EAP X](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+X+EAP): " IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate EAP - You need to have a valid IntelliJ IDEA 10 license in order to use this EAP build."

Comment: @NimChimpsky: The licensing may have changed, of course, but the page I quote is from 2011, and I have not found any later, different information.

Comment: @sleske you use an eval license. its a valid license for 30days. You then get the new eap and start again.

Comment: @NimChimpsky: Well, I don't think IntelliJ's terms allow renewing an evaluation license. At any rate, I don't see what this has to do with the EAP version - or is there some difference in the licensing rules?

Answer (score 5):

You may use IDEA Community Edition for editing the code, you just won't get any features specific to the servers you're using, e.g. run configurations. You'll have to launch your application using the command line. You'll be able to use Artifacts feature to build all the jars you need.

You won't get any Spring-specific code completion or code inspections, but you'll get a decent XML editor for its configuration files. You'll get some basic HTML editing features, but no JavaScript.

There's no way to get those features out of IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition source, they just aren't there.

BTW if you use Ultimate EAP as NimChimpsky suggests, and report plenty of bugs, the developers might be grateful for them and give you a free license in return at the moment of the release (around December).