# How to add JPA support to a java web-app project

Tags: hibernate, intellij-idea, jpa-2.0, intellij-plugin

I am trying to enable JPA support in a sample java webapp project.

The official [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-jpa-support.html) says:

> To enable JPA support in an existing module
>   Open the Module Settings dialog box.
>   With the desired module selected, click + on the toolbar, and select JPA from the list of facets available for this module.
>   Click the JPA facet node. The right pane of the dialog box shows the facet options.

But I can't seem to find the JPA facet. Is there anything else that I need to do to have access to the JPA facet?

I am using IntelliJ idea 12.1.3 community version

Comment: what version of IntelliJ are you using.  I have v11.15 and that facet shows up.

Comment: which flavour of Intellij do you have, Community or Ultimate? Notice that the official documentation says 'Some features described here are available in Ultimate edition only.'

Comment: @user3360944 I am using Intellij Idea 12.1.3 community version

Answer (score 0):

JPA is available in IntelliJ Idea ULTIMATE EDITION... Check the Community vs Ultimate edition comparison here: [IntelliJ Community editionvs Ultimate Edition comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

If u want to use JavaEE classes in community edition check this answer to a question on stackoverflow : [How to use Java EE IntelliJ IDEA community edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698847/how-to-use-java-ee-intellij-idea-community-edition)

For a better explanation : [Can IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition support Ultimate's features somehow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19091946/can-intellij-idea-community-edition-support-ultimates-features-somehow)